# Variable 'hasil' is used uninitialized whenever 'if' condition is false

Tags: c++, xcode, if-statement, syntax, warnings

I'm a beginner and I'm making this simple calculator for my assignment:

```cpp
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a,b,hasil;
    char aritmatika;
    
    cout <<"Selamat datang di Program Calculator Sederhana \n \n";
    
    //Memasukkan input dari user
    
    cout <<"Silahkan masukkan nilai pertamamu: ";
    cin >>a;
    
    cout <<"Pilih operator+,-,*,/: ";
    cin >>aritmatika;
    
    cout <<"Silahkan masukkan nilai keduamu: ";
    cin >>b;
    
    cout <<"\n \nHasil Perhitungan:\n\n";
    cout <<a <<aritmatika <<b;
    
    if(aritmatika =='+'){
        hasil = a+b;
    }else if(aritmatika =='-'){
        hasil = a-b;
    }else if(aritmatika =='*'){
        hasil = a*b;
    }else if(aritmatika =='/'){
        hasil = a/b;
    }else{
        cout <<"Operator yang anda masukkan salah"<<endl;
    }
    cout << "= " << hasil << endl;
        
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

But then there's this warning saying that .

```
else if(aritmatika =='/'){
    hasil = a/b;
```

I don't understand why it shows that `hasil` is uninitialized and when I erased that line, the same thing goes with the `else if` on top of it.
I copied my teacher's code and it's still not working and not running. I'll appreciate it if you can help me!

Comment: The variable is not initialized in the very last `else` block. If this is your teacher's code, then you'd better find another teacher.

Answer (score 0):

What if *aritmatika* is not equal to any of the 4 options for which you are testing, because the user entered an incorrect option? Then *hasil* is never initialized to a value. So as a variable you've defined but not initialized, that bit of memory allocated to hold *hasil* does not have a value assigned to it. In the final *cout* you are trying to use *hasil* even though there's a chance it has no value assigned to it. So the compiler is trying to warn you that there's a possibility that your variable will be uninitialized. So you could do as follows:

```
bool validOperator = true;

if (aritmatika == '+') {
    hasil = a + b;
}
else if (aritmatika == '-') {
    hasil = a - b;
}
else if (aritmatika == '*') {
    hasil = a * b;
}
else if (aritmatika == '/') {
    hasil = a / b;
}
else {
    validOperator = false;
    cout << "Operator yang anda masukkan salah" << endl;
}

if (validOperator)
    cout << "= " << hasil << endl;
```